# Could the accuracy of high-resolution timers (HRTs) be "really" 1ns？

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

You could see the accuracy of high-resolution timers (HRTs) is 1ns through `cat /proc/timer_list | grep resolution`.

As it's all known that the **frequency of CPU is just about 1-3GHz**, how could the accuracy of HRTs be 1ns?

```
$ cat /proc/timer_list | grep resolution
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
  .resolution: 1 nsecs
```

Comment: Timers are simple counters, resolution is being defined by the input clock. As you noticed yourself the clock of 1GHz is enough to have such resolution. I think you stumbled over another Q, i.e. _may I get a timer interval within few nanoseconds?_ No, you may not, because setting it up and managing IRQ will cost more. So, read what **resolution** means (hint: physics at school).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.I promise that i have graduated already.But, i still could not get the idea about resolution.Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Resolution is not the duration of the measurement. 1ns resolution doesn't mean that the timer will be able to run every 1ns, it only means that the result will be accurate to the nanosecond. The timer could take 2 seconds to measure but still be accurate to the nanosecond.

Comment: I see,thank you for the clarification.One more question, the clock of 1GHz is enough to have such resolution.But, **could the colck really achieve 1GHz?**